# Preprocess Data for Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, preprocessor

I have a .csv File that has hundreds of thousands of lines. The information was collected in order by the user.

For example, one user's inputs may range 20-400 rows, and the corresponding target is a single row where the users first input row started.

inputs | Targets

0, 7

1

2

3

4

So one set of targets per x amount of input rows.

Some of my columns contain '-' I feel like this will mess up my model when trying to train, considering it isn't a float or int what I should do?

Also, Should I shuffle my data if it is chunked like this?

Comment: Is it a classification problem, if not can you specify your Target range?